# My program is rebelling? Changes are not made

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have an annoying problem with Visual Studio. Indeed, I am in the design of a compiler, and I have a file reserved for error messages. It works with a dictionary (std::map): code → message.

However, the changes made to the dictionary do not seem to affect the program, which reacts as if no changes had been made.

It would be difficult for me to explain more clearly with words, so I recorded [a video](https://streamable.com/xehke). (It does not belong to the site, sorry, I did not find how to include it i, this post).

As you can see, we use a function that displays the error message as it gets it from the dictionary :

```
std::map<ErrorCodes, std::string> Messages;
...
std::string ErrMessage = Messages[code];
```

I do not understand why the changes made do not affect the program as intended. It seems that Visual Studio no longer compiles part of the code...

Indeed, in the recording, we can see that the error message displayed in the console is the [E29] (the old one before the [E80]), and that the message displayed is not the one that corresponds with the enumeration either.

The problem may seem simple, but I honestly do not see where it might lie...

EDIT:

Here is a more detailed explanation:

In the video, the program running in the console is mine. "Compilation not success" is my own error message, and it is normal that it is displayed.

Here is the call code of the error call display:

```
exception.ThrowError(exception.E0080);
```

E0080 is the error listing code, here are the error message files :

*.hpp:

```
class Exception {
public:
    enum ErrorCodes {
        E0000,
        E0001, //  Can't load file
        E0002, //  Can't find header file
        E0003, //  Expected file name
        E0004, //  Unexpected token
        E0005, //  Expected Identifier
        E0006, //  Value without storage object
        E0007, //  Already existing object
        E0008, //  Redefined preprocessor definition
        E0009, //  Redefined variable
        E0010, //  Redefined function
        E0011, //  Redefined object
        E0012, //  Redefined rule
        E0013, //  Redefined value
        E0014, //  Undefined identifier
        E0015, //  Buoyage symbol missing
        E0016, //  Expected end of line symbol (';')
        E0017, //  Unexpected character
        E0018, //  Unknown token
        E0019, //  Non-close comment
        E0020, //  Non-compliant typing
        E0021, //  Use of uninitialized data
        E0022, //  Unacceptable suffix
        E0023, //  Invalid keyword combination
        E0024, //  Declaration not in accordance with non-local use
        E0025, //  Incompatible value with type / object defined
        E0026, //  Constant value too wide
        E0027, //  Too much initialization value in a static size array
        E0028, //  Non-conforming identifier
        E0029, //  Expected statement
        E0030, //  Wrong identifier format (the expected format is ASCII)
        E0031, //  Wrong pointer initialization
        E0032, //  Non-valid literal suffix
        E0033, //  No object can have the identifier 'vanaur'
        E0034, //  Non-existent object field
        E0035, //  Non-existent object method
        E0036, //  Missing function call arguments
        E0037, //  A rvalue cannot be accessed via the pointers
        E0038, //  The use of a pointer is unacceptable in this context
        E0039, //  A reference cannot be made to a constant value
        E0040, //  Invalid assembler code in external expression
        E0041, //  The types of the two objects do not match in the image assignment
        E0042, //  Only a defined object can be destroyed by the delete operator
        E0043, //  Empty template
        E0044, //  Object not existing in this namespace
        E0045, //  Typage temptation with a non-instanciated structure
        E0046, //  Temptation to access a private field of the object
        E0047, //  Temptation to access a private method of the object
        E0048, //  Invalid operator
        E0049, //  Reserved identifier
        E0050, //  Wrong usage of postfix and prefix operator
        E0051, //  Temptation to access an inaccessible element in a table
        E0052, //  The main function can only have 3 arguments variation
        E0053, //  This function is not defined as being able to return an array
        E0054, //  A non-instanciated structure cannot be used as an object instance with the keyword 'new'.
        E0055, //  Wrong choice of the anonymous string concatenation operator (between '^' and'+')
        E0056, //  An object can only inherit from one other object
        E0057, //  Incorrect 'typename' value
        E0058, //  Incorrect 'typesize' value
        E0059, //  The identifier of a process ('proc') cannot contain spaces
        E0060, //  The identifier of a process ('proc') cannot contain balises
        E0061, //  An exception cannot be thrown out of a function
        E0062, //  Syntax error
        E0063, //  The increment value of an iteration (with step) must be numerical
        E0064, //  An anonymous array serving as an iterator to a for loop cannot be empty
        E0065, //  Wrong ternary condition format
        E0066, //  A 'ret' instruction must only fit on one instruction (one line = one ';')
        E0067, //  Division by zero
        E0068, //  Wrong enumeration value
        E0069, //  'Upon' block members cannot contain expressions other than 'it'
        E0070, //  A match/case expression must contain at least one 'case' expression before using 'default'
        E0071, //  Unknown error
        E0072, //  Undefined object
        E0073, //  Not a valid math expression
        E0074, //  Expected character
        E0075, //  Unbalanced brackets
        E0076, //  Non-ascii character detected
        E0077, //  The current version of Arlia only accepts constant values as optional function parameters
        E0078, //  Undefined type
        E0079, //  Statement not recognised in this context
        E0080, //  Invalid statement
    };
    void ThrowError(ErrorCodes, char);
    void ThrowError(ErrorCodes, std::string);
    void ThrowError(ErrorCodes, token_t);
    void ThrowError(ErrorCodes, token_t, Expr);
    void ThrowError(ErrorCodes, Expr);
private:
    std::map<ErrorCodes, std::string> Messages =
    {
        { E0001, " Can't load file" },
    { E0002, " Can't find header file" },
    { E0003, " Expected file name" },
    { E0004, " Unexpected token" },
    { E0005, " Expected Identifier" },
    { E0006, " Value without storage object" },
    { E0007, " Already existing object" },
    { E0008, " Redefined preprocessor definition" },
    { E0009, " Redefined variable" },
    { E0010, " Redefined function" },
    { E0011, " Redefined object" },
    { E0012, " Redefined rule" },
    { E0013, " Redefined value" },
    { E0014, " Undefined identifier" },
    { E0015, " Buoyage symbol missing" },
    { E0016, " Expected end of line symbol (';')" },
    { E0017, " Unexpected character" },
    { E0018, " Unknown token" },
    { E0019, " Non-close comment" },
    { E0020, " Non-compliant typing" },
    { E0021, " Use of uninitialized data" },
    { E0022, " Unacceptable suffix" },
    { E0023, " Invalid keyword combination" },
    { E0024, " Declaration not in accordance with non-local use" },
    { E0025, " Incompatible value with type / object defined" },
    { E0026, " Constant value too wide" },
    { E0027, " Too much initialization value in a static size array" },
    { E0028, " Non-conforming identifier" },
    { E0029, " Expected statement" },
    { E0030, " Wrong identifier format (the expected format is ASCII)" },
    { E0031, " Wrong pointer initialization" },
    { E0032, " Non-valid literal suffix" },
    { E0033, " No object can have the identifier 'vanaur'" },
    { E0034, " Non-existent object field" },
    { E0035, " Non-existent object method" },
    { E0036, " Missing function call arguments" },
    { E0037, " A rvalue cannot be accessed via the pointers" },
    { E0038, " The use of a pointer is unacceptable in this context" },
    { E0039, " A reference cannot be made to a constant value" },
    { E0040, " Invalid assembler code in external expression" },
    { E0041, " The types of the two objects do not match in the image assignment" },
    { E0042, " Only a defined object can be destroyed by the delete operator" },
    { E0043, " Empty template" },
    { E0044, " Object not existing in this namespace" },
    { E0045, " Typage temptation with a non-instanciated structure" },
    { E0046, " Temptation to access a private field of the object" },
    { E0047, " Temptation to access a private method of the object" },
    { E0048, " Invalid operator" },
    { E0049, " Reserved identifier" },
    { E0050, " Wrong usage of postfix and prefix operator" },
    { E0051, " Temptation to access an inaccessible element in a table" },
    { E0052, " The main function can only have 3 arguments variation" },
    { E0053, " This function is not defined as being able to return an array" },
    { E0054, " A non-instanciated structure cannot be used as an object instance with the keyword 'new'" },
    { E0055, " Wrong choice of the anonymous string concatenation operator (between '^' and'+')" },
    { E0056, " An object can only inherit from one other object" },
    { E0057, " Incorrect 'typename' value" },
    { E0058, " Incorrect 'typesize' value" },
    { E0059, " The identifier of a process ('proc') cannot contain spaces" },
    { E0060, " The identifier of a process ('proc') cannot contain balises" },
    { E0061, " An exception cannot be thrown out of a function" },
    { E0062, " Syntax error" },
    { E0063, " The increment value of an iteration (with step) must be numerical" },
    { E0064, " An anonymous array serving as an iterator to a for loop cannot be empty" },
    { E0065, " Wrong ternary condition format" },
    { E0066, " A 'ret' instruction must only fit on one instruction (one line = one ';')" },
    { E0067, " Division by zero" },
    { E0068, " Wrong enumeration value" },
    { E0069, " 'Upon' block members cannot contain expressions other than 'it'" },
    { E0070, " A match/case expression must contain at least one 'case' expression before using 'default'" },
    { E0071, " Unknown error" },
    { E0072, " Undefined object" },
    { E0073, " Not a valid math expression" },
    { E0074, " Expected character" },
    { E0075, " Unbalanced brackets" },
    { E0076, " Non-ascii character detected" },
    { E0077, " The current version of Arlia only accepts constant values as optional function parameters" },
    { E0078, " Undefined type" },
    { E0079, " Statement not recognised in this context" },
    { E0080, " Invalid statement" },

    { E0000, " ... " }
    };
};
```

The *.cpp just implements the functions as follows :

```
ThrowError(ErrorCodes code) {
    colored_message_error("[ E" + std::to_string(code) + " ]" + Messages[code], Color::yellow);
}
```

As you can see, the list contains 80 + 1 elements. And E0080 has 80 as index in the enumeration.

When I try to access it:

```
exception.ThrowError(exception.E0080);
```

my program doesn't seem to want to update the information. That is, the enumeration constant sent to the function: in fact, the program displays the value I set before it (E29).

It's exactly like I'm doing this:

```
exception.ThrowError(exception.E0029);
```

So, no, it's most likely not a stupid debugging or compiling problem (I still know how to use a compiler ^^). It seems strange that Visual Studio does not update this new data (how ? why ? is it ?).

Comment: What changes are you making? Nothing changes in the code here. That's an empty `std::map` container. Please don't include videos, do your best to describe what the problem is in the body of your question. External links are nothing but trouble for many users.

Comment: [mcve] is what you need.  Failing that, you need a debugging tutorial?  Not sure what you want us to do with this.

Comment: In your video I keep seeing the message "Compilation non success" appear -- so the most likely explanation as to why the executable's behavior isn't changing is that the compile is failing, and thus the old executable (from the last version of the source code that did compile) is the one you are running, and it doesn't contain your recent changes.  (You might want to find your program's .exe file and delete it; that way the next time you run your program, you'll know it was something freshly compiled and not an old version)

Comment: To expand on @JeremyFriesner's comment, in Visual Studio, use <Ctrl>-<Alt>-F7 to do a full clean and rebuild.  That'll make sure your executable is completely up to date.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I edited the original message to get more information. I hope you understand my problem.

Comment: I also try to clean  and rebuild, but the problem seems stay...

Comment: I like the term *"My program is rebelling"*.  I've had programs and system that rebelling and seemed they had tempers too.

Comment: If it's not a problem with the program failing to compile, then perhaps it is a problem with a different source/header-file being read instead of the file that you are editing.  Try temporarily inserting a `#error hey_man_are_you_even_reading_this` line into the file that you are editing, right above (or below) the line(s) you are trying to change, and then do a full recompile of your program.  If you don't see the compiler trip over that `#error` directive, that is a good clue that your file isn't being read (and presumably some other file with the same name is being read instead)